# MPMoviePlayerController - AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification called not right

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter, avsystemcontroller

I have `MPMoviePlayerController` and i m trying to get notify when user change the volume.

I listen to this event: `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` by this code:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(moviePlayerVolumeChanged:)
        name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
      object:nil];
```

And i catch the notification in:

```
- (void)moviePlayerVolumeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    klogdbg_func
    // GA
    [self trackVideoPlayerGAEvent:@"Change Volume"];
}
```

The problem is that my player notify me 4 times when the movie start/finish loading, **without** any volume change by the user.

Why that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it that you are hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: Google analytics- track over user's events...

Comment: Ok, I got such tracking requirements as well in the past and answered them by: not possible.